# Java EE Module Dependencies in web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have this webprojec to which I have to add a jar from another EJB project.
Normally I'd right-click the webproject and go to properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies.
I don't know if it is because I upgraded eclipse, or i'm doing something wrong, but I just can't find the "Java EE Module Dependencies" in the properties window.
Both projects are linked with the same EAR so the EJB jar file shuld be there!

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or some other way I could attach the EJB's JAR file? I'm only allowed to work with eclipse, so netbeans is not an option.

Thanks!

EDIT:
basically, [this is what I want to do](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/ideuserguide/projects/conProjectDependencies.html), but that specific panel won't show up...

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: The newest version, so I'm guessing they either moved this feature or I'm doing something wrong.

It's Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521

My old installation kept crashing on me, so I upgraded, and now I'm missing this option... (I think)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer on the eclipse irc channel, this feature was renamed and redone as "Deployment Assembly" in the project properties.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sled. You saved me a lot of headache :)
I was struggling with the same problem. Well, not anymore.